# Complex root of a real polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We consider, in $\mathbb R[X]$, the polynomial  $$C_{n}=X(X+1)^{2n}-2^nX.$$
>   Determine the values of $n$ for which the complex number $i$ is a root of $C_n$.

My thoughts:
note that $$(1+i)^2=2i$$

$i$ is root of $C_n$ then 
\begin{align}
C_{n}(i)&=0\\
i(i+1)^{2n}-2^ni&=0\\
i(2i)^{n}-2^ni&=0
\end{align}
if $n$ is even then $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n=2k$ then 
$$i(2i)^{(2k)}-2^{2k}i=0$$

if $n$ is odd then $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n=2k+1$ then 
$$i(2i)^{(2k+1)}-2^{2k+1}i=0$$

update

can we see that n multiple of 4 through
$$\text{arg} ( (1+i)^{2n} )=n \text{arg}(2i)=n \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. To continue, write
$$
C(i)=i(2i)^{n}-2^ni=i2^n(i^n-1)
$$
It remains to find those $n$ such that $i^n-1=0$, that is, $i^n=1$: they are exacty the multiples of $4$, because the powers of $i$ repeat in a cycle $1,i,-1,-i$.

Comment: Thanks but could u make complet proof

Comment: could you elbaorate please the part $i^n=1$ implies that they are exactly the multiples of $4$

Comment: @Educ: $i^2 = -1$, so $i^4 = 1$, so $i^8 = i^4 \times i^4 = 1$, and $i^{12} = i^8 \times i^4 = 1$, etc.

Comment: can we see that through $$\text{arg} ( (1+i)^{2n} )=n \text{arg}(2i)=n \frac{\pi}{4}$$